# Unity New Tag or Layer and Applying to Object without reselecting in inspector afterwards

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a quicker/more convenient way to apply new Tags and Layers to GameObjects. Currently I go to inspector, click on a game object

[image]

Then click on the drop down for tag or layer, create new tag or create new layer, then I have to select the GameObject again in the inspector, go back and tag it, or set its layer. I mean its working, its fine, but its a little slow, especially with multiple objects. Is there a quicker way?